# Link to subpages on the same page

Tags: dropdown, sub-menu

I'm using a dropdown menu on my Wordpress page which shows all the pages. If you hover over it, the subpages of that particular page are shown. Say I have five pages that each have a couple of subpages. Is it possible to show the subpages on the same page as the page itself and have the dropdown menu link to the section of the page where the subpage is listed?

Hope this is clear. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) is the most straightforward way to get "attachments, revisions, or sub-Pages". So...

```
$children = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID));
if (!empty($children)) {
  foreach ($children as $child) {
    echo '<div id="child-'.$child->ID.'" >';
      // content formatted however you want
    echo '</div>';
}
```

See the Codex page for further parameters that you might need.

I don't know how you've constructed your drop-down menu but you can link to any element on the page using its `id` attribute so your `href` for the links should be `#child-<ID>`, preferably constructed as an absolute URL.